# How to simulate a rest API?

Tags: api, rest

I am working on a new project which will query data from a 3rd party REST API. This is for a real time sports data feed, so the feed only works when a game is actually taking place.

Although the 3rd party provides good documentation (XSD, etc), they have no way to simulate a game happening, and so to test code I have written against this API I would have to wait for an actual game to be happening.

My only recourse is to write code to simulate a game on my own, but it seems like a lot of work. Has anyone any experience with any tools similar to [Apiary](http://www.apiary.io) to do this? How would you approach this?

Thanks